# How can I specialize a template which depends on a static data member of a class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider the following code. I want to specialize `std::hash<>` used in a `Map`, according to the value of a static data member of the Array class. Note that Array depends on `Map` itself.

```
// Array.h
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Array;
typedef pair<int, int> Point;

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<Point> {
        size_t operator()(const Point & p) const {
            return p.second * Array::C + p.first; // error: incomplete type ‘Array’ used in nested name specifier
        }
    };
}

typedef unordered_map<Point, Array, hash<Point> > Map;

class Array {
public:
    static const int R = 5, C = 5;
    Map compute() {/*...*/}
};
```

Of course, in the above specialization `Array` is not complete yet, so the compiler complains. However, if I move the specialization below the class definition, I obtain another error:

> `error: specialization of ‘std::hash<std::pair<int, int> >’ after instantiation`

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it is an UB to change or specialize classes in the std namespace

Comment: @VJovic: You may _specialize_ templates in namespace `std`. You must not _overload_ function templates, though. (Note that there's no _partial specialization_ for function templates, you have to use overloading instead — which is forbidden. Hence you can specialize `std::swap<>()` for your `foo` class, but not for — all instances of — your `bar<T>` template.)

Comment: I think it is possible under some conditions stated by the standard. I am almost sure the above case does not violate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you pretty much know the reason why you're getting that error, so I wouldn't explain that. However, if you want to explore that part also, then I will definitely explain that.

As for how to solve this problem, alright, I would do three things:

- First, I wouldn't specialize `std::hash` to begin with!
- Second, I would write my own `MyHash` class template, which I would instantiate with `Array` type, instead of `Point` type. Also note that the parameter type to `operator()` isn't `Array`, rather it is `Point` , as it should be.
- Third, I would move the `typedef` of `Map` inside the class `Array`.

Here is what I mean:

```
template <typename A> 
struct MyHash
{
   size_t operator()(const Point & p) const 
   {
     return p.second * A::C + p.first;
   }
};

class Array {
public:
    typedef unordered_map<Point, Array, MyHash<Array> > Map;
    static const int R = 5, C = 5;
    Map compute() {/*...*/}
};
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/hwLIT

Answer (score 1):

You are using the static member before the class is defined. Fix this by moving the implementation of `hash` after `Array`:

```
// Array.h
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Array;
typedef pair<int, int> Point;

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<Point>;
}

typedef unordered_map<Point, Array, hash<Point> > Map;
class Array {
public:
    static const int R = 5, C = 5;
    Map compute();
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<Point> {
        size_t operator()(const Point & p) const {
            return p.second * Array::C + p.first;
        }
    };
}
```